# c# QueryString exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

In the following code, I got following error.

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative
>   and less than the size of the collection.

the Code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Prid.Text = Request.QueryString[0];
    using (SqlConnection connection = ConnectionManager.GetConnection())
    {
        string cmd = "SELECT ImageColor, Quantity, ProductName, Price, ScreenSize, ScreenType, Processor, Internal_Memory, Ram, SD_Card, Camera, Bettery From Mobtabspecifications WHERE Mobtabspecifications.Prid ='" + Prid.Text+"'";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        { 
            img.ImageUrl = "../image/"+ reader[0] as string;
            Quantity.Text = reader[1] as string;
            PrName.Text = reader[2] as string;
            PrPrice.Text = reader[3] as string;
            SSize.Text = reader[4] as string;
            SType.Text = reader[5] as string;
            Prpower.Text = reader[6] as string;
            Intmemory.Text = reader[7] as string;
            Ram.Text = reader[8] as string;
            sdcard.Text = reader[9] as string;
            Camera.Text = reader[10] as string;
            Bettery.Text = reader[11] as string;
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

if i want to active the product after that & i need to set the products in the basket by the id if any one have any idea about that please tell me in a comment

Comment: Request.QueryString doesn't contain elements

Comment: Please remove unrelated SQL injection sample as it makes post look bad.

Comment: What's the query string you are passing to this page? Prevent SQL Injection by avoiding string concatenation, use parameterized queries. Refer http://bobby-tables.com

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the name of each column:

```
Quantity.Text = reader["Quantity"] as string;
```

instead of

```
Quantity.Text = reader[1] as string;
```